# Exclude terminating error from try/catch PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-4.0

I am having difficulty in checking if a group exists or not via a Rest API.

Call the Api to check if the Group exists. My logic: Use the 'Invoke-RestMethod' to call the API. If the API call is successful (Group exists) it will store the result in '$reader_response_success', if the group does not exist, the cmdlet will fail, the error details are stored in the Error Variable '$reader_response_failure'.

Depending on which variable has values, I can conclude whether group exists or not. However, our framework has a Try/Catch implementation. So, in case if the group does not exist, the entire script will STOP executing.

How can I make sure that the script will continue execution even if the API call fails. (As I know that the API call will fail if the group does not exist). I have given $errorAction as 'SilentlyContinue' but still it STOPS the script execution.

```
function Test-CoeAzureInstancePowerBI{

param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    $ServiceConfiguration
)

## TODO: Check if the Reader and Creator Group exists in dwgm 
# Checking if ReaderGroup exists
$Group = @{
GroupName = "ITGA_" + $ServiceConfiguration.ReaderGroup
}
$json = $Group | ConvertTo-Json 
$reader_response_success = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.corpinter.net/dwgm/v1/lookup/' -Headers $ServiceConfiguration.Headers -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -ErrorVariable $reader_response_failure -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# In the above api call, 
# $reader_response_success contains data if the group exists
# $reader_response_failure contains data if the group does not exist
if($reader_response_success -eq $null) {$ServiceConfiguration.ReaderGroupExists = $False}

# Checking if ReaderGroup exists
$Group = @{
GroupName = "ITGA_" + $ServiceConfiguration.CreatorGroup
}
$json = $Group | ConvertTo-Json 
$creator_response_success = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.corpinter.net/dwgm/v1/lookup/' -Headers $ServiceConfiguration.Headers -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -ErrorVariable $creator_response_failure -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# In the above api call, 
# $creator_response_success contains data if the group exists
# $creator_response_failure contains data if the group does not exist
if($creator_response_success -eq $null) {$ServiceConfiguration.CreatorGroupExists = $False}


## The instance should be SKIPPED only if both the ReaderGroup and CreatorGroup exist 
if($ServiceConfiguration.CreatorGroupExists -eq $true -and $ServiceConfiguration.ReaderGroupExists -eq $true){
    return $true
}else{
 return $False
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` will continue on non-terminating errors only. So you probably get a terminating error. You can just do your own error handling for that particular cmdlet:

```bsh
try {
    $reader_response_success = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.corpinter.net/dwgm/v1/lookup/' -Headers $ServiceConfiguration.Headers -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'
} catch {
    # Do some error handling here (probably nothing according to your code so far)
}
```

Do the same for the second `Invoke-RestMethod` call.

Comment: Thank you. If I get an error, i do not want the control to go inside the catch. I want the control to go to the next line after 'Invoke-RestMethod'. Is this possible for 'terminating' error?

Comment: @ManjunathRao Yes, just use the code from this answer. Put your code, that follows `Invoke-RestMethod`, after the catch block. Leave the catch block empty as the comment already suggests. My answer is designed to replace each line of your `Invoke-RestMethod` calls.